# VB.NET - How to calculate an average of values from textbox's

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to visual basic and I'm using visual studio 2008 express edition.

I need to create a program to calculate a grade / average.

Do I need to repeat if / then / else statements for each textbox?

Please Refer to the linked image below for reference.

[image]

I'm not sure how to average these values.

Would I need to create many, repeated conditional statements?

Comment: Hi Rain - Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)- please take the time to have a look at this page [ask] - It's extremely helpful in showing how to ask good questions - Usually SO is for people who have written some code and are still having problems - Have a search on google for "grade calculator" there are plenty of useful results - Adapt the code to you needs and if you're still having problems - post a new question to include code that you have so far, what you want it to do and what it actually does and any errors you're getting.

Comment: Calculating an average is the same, no matter what language you use or how you obtain the input. Add the values together, divide by the number of values, and you have the average. What part of that in particular are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Dim tbList As TextBox() = {txtMath, txtEnglish, txtScience, txtFilipino, txtPE}
            Dim Ave As Double = 0

            For Each item In tbList

                If item.Text = Nothing Then

                    item.Text = "0"

                End If

                Ave += Val(item.Text)

            Next

            Ave = Ave / tbList.Length

            lb_Average.Text = Ave.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with a few if statements, that add 1 point each to a variable IF the textbox has a value. Repeat that statement for each textbox.

Then, add up the values of each textbox.

Finally, divide the sum of the values of each text box by the number of textboxes that contain a value, which you would have counted using the if / then statements earlier.

So, in the calculate button's click event, it may look something like this (Written in vb.net) :

```
Dim Count as Integer = 0
If txtMath.text <> "" Then Count += 1
If txtEnglish.text <> "" Then Count += 1
If txtScience.text <> "" Then Count += 1
If txtFilipino.text <> "" Then Count += 1
If txtPE.text <> "" Then Count += 1

Dim Sum as decimal = (txtmath.text + txtenglish.text + txtScience.text + txtFilipino.text + txtPE.text) / Count
```

Comment: Adding text won't add numerical values but rather concat them, hence not giving the expected thing (and with Option Strict On won't even compile)

Comment: Sorry, I'm half asleep. I couldn't remember whether those would convert implicitly... In that case than obviously we'd need to put Convert.toint32(...) around each of those text values to convert them to numerical values...